# The limit of the sum of the terms of a series

Tags: limits

Let $(a_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ be a series which converges to $-1$ and $(b_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ a series which diverges to $-\infty$. Calculate the limit of $\sum ^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n$ and the limit of $\sum ^{\infty}_{n=1} b_n$.

I'm not sure if the limit is always calculable, but the answers of the book that contains this exercise say $\infty$ respectively $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Both sums should diverge to $-\infty$, by similar arguments.

For $(a_n)$, since it converges to $-1$, we can pick any $\varepsilon > 0$ and know that for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $n \geq N \implies |a_n + 1| \lt \varepsilon$. For example, choose $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, so we then have that $|a_n + 1| \lt \frac{1}{2} \iff -\frac{3}{2} \lt a_n \lt -\frac{1}{2}$. Then $\sum_0^\infty a_n = \sum_0^{N-1} a_n + \sum_N^\infty a_n < \sum_0^{N-1} a_n + \sum_N^\infty -\frac{1}{2} = \sum_0^{N-1} a_n - \frac{1}{2} \sum_N^\infty 1$ which clearly diverges to $-\infty$.